# OpenCV: how to get yaw, roll, pitch from POSIT (solvePnP) rotation matrix

Tags: opencv

what is the algorithm used to calculate the yaw(z axis), roll(x axis) and pitch(y axis) from the 3*3 rotation matrix generated by cvPOSIT.

Comment: Note: cvPOSIT has been replaced by solvePnP, though is still available in the C api

Answer (score 3):

Use [`cv::RQDecomp3x3()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=euler#rqdecomp3x3).
*"It optionally returns three rotation matrices, one for each axis, and the three Euler angles in degrees (as the return value)"*.
Note that the results are degrees.